# Why do unicode strings show garbage?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, unicode

I am attempting to generate a message box with unicode characters in it, but the output is not what I am expecting.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE , HINSTANCE , PWSTR , int )
{
    MessageBox(NULL,L"cyrillic АЖ\nchinese ",L"top Ж bott ",MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
    return 0;
}
/*
compiled using
cl /c /Wall test4.cpp
link -out:test4.exe test4.obj user32.lib
*/
```

Output as run on windows 10

[image: result dialog window]

The compiler is Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition

Comment: are your source file is saved as unicode ?

Comment: Save your file as UTF-8 and tell the compiler to use UTF-8 for the source encoding and string literals, e.g. with the `/utf-8` command-line option of cl.exe.

Comment: thanks. The /utf-8 switch solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

What I was doing wrong was not to use the /utf-8 compiler switch, as pointed out by eryksun.

> Save your file as UTF-8 and tell the compiler to use UTF-8 for the source encoding and string literals, e.g. with the /utf-8 command-line option of cl.exe. – eryksun